# Httpd/Apache. PHP. mod_rewrite. Fedora 17

Tags: mod-rewrite, configuration, fedora, apache

I' trying to install sweetcron and it needs mod_rewrite enabled.
So, what's the easiest way to do this on Fedora 17?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit your `httpd.conf` (by default it lies in `/etc/httpd/conf/`)

Change option `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

After that restart your Apache server.

---

You can test your rewrite engine by some simple redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Thanks to the quick answer.I changed the section in *<Directory "/var/www/html">* to *AllowOverride All*. So, I just need run *sudo service httpd restart* and will work?

Comment: @GarouDan Exactly. You can check if your changes applied by creating simple .htaccess file with some redirect in it.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are multiple lines you may need to change this, depending on which directory you would like to chage